# Using "subject to" with a verb other than "to be"

Tags: verbs, adjectives, adverbs

Is it possible to use *subject to* with a verb other than *to be*?

for example:

> The self-image is subject to changes. (Obviously OK)
>
> Being bound to our self-image we react subject to behavior patterns. (Is it OK??)

Are there any good alternatives to this construction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second sentence is fine. *Subject to* is an adverb phrase that means [conditionally upon](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/subject?q=subject+to#subject__15).

"Reacting conditionally upon something" is fine.

Other examples:

- We can alter the designs subject to your agreement.
- You will only shoot subject to strict guidelines.
- Awarding the degree is subject to you completing the course.